# React-testing-library intermittent Rejected error

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

currently im using React-testing-library on my CRA app and specifically 1 test that has the intermittent issue and it's always `Rejected`, it doesn't give any info on what is really the problem
[image]

Thats the error, it just says `Rejected`, and you can see `[DEBUG] NUMBER` is im trying to find where the error stops, but the `[DEBUG] 22` is the last line on my test meaning it goes through all the code

[image]

and most of the tests code just getting the role or text. Any idea how to find whats the problem on this? Thanks

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, don't post screenshots of the code

Comment: I can't provide because it only happens on our CI, on my local development it never happened